# maximizing an alternating sum with reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, summation, maxima-minima

I have the following maximization problem, which I believe should have been studied before.

Let $n=3$ and fix $t$. I want to maximize $-\Big(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a} \Big)-\frac{1}{a+b+c}$ where the maximization is over $a,b,c>0$ tuples of integers satisfying $a+b+c=t$.

Note that this is a baby version of the case for general $n$. So for general $n$, I want to maximize a sum (similar to the one above with alternating signs) with $n$ variables $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ (satisfying $\sum_i a_i=t$).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
After considering that $a, b, c$ are positive integers, I believe you can achieve the maximum value by keeping $a, b, c$ as close to as $t/3$, i.e the average of them. Also, if there are $n$ variables, then you should set them around $t/n$. I'd say, give each of them $[|t/n|]$ and give some of them 1 more as many times as the remainder. Like for $t=25$ and $n=4$, go for $6,6,6,7$.

But this is just what I feel after a very brief observation; I have no proof for it. If what I say is correct, then it is still a hard work to calculate that maximum value, because that almost-equal distribution of $t$ to $n$ variables will not be fully equal because of the condition that variables are integers and I guess for every remainder of $t/n$ you should make a calculation to find out that maximum number. But some good news, if what I say is correct, then you can make a computer compute it for you.

That expression is maximally infinity. Just take $b=c=t/2$ and choose $a=-0$ (a approaches to zero from the left side), and $1/a$ will become negative infinity and the other fractions will remain finite and notice that there is a minus behind the parantheses where $1/a$ takes place which will make it positive infinity. Similarly if you choose $a=+0$, then you will get minus infinity as the minimal value.

End of Edit 1

Edit 2:

If t has a remainder of 0 in divison by 3, then let $t=3x$, then set $a=b=c=x$, according to my approach maximum should be $-3/(2x)$

If t has a remainder of 1 in division by 3, then let $t=3x+1$, then set $a=b=x$ and $c=x+1$, according to my approach maximum should be $-1/(2x(x+1))$

If t has a remainder of 2 in division by 3, then let $t=3x+2$, then set $a=x$, $b=c=x+1$, according to my approach maximum should be $-1/(2x(x+1)(2x+1))$

But again for a generalized solution for $n$ based on the the remainder of $t$ divided by $n$, you should try harder, there must be a pattern.

End of Edit 2

For your expression to have maximally finite limit, you should remove the first minus sign. Then the solution will be as follows:

For n=3:
Use the inequality that the arithmetic mean is bigger than or equal to harmonic mean (they are equal only when all elements are the same).

$$(a+b+c)/3 > 3/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c)$$
$$t/3 > 3/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c)$$
$$t/9 > 1/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c)$$

$$((a+b)+(b+c)+(c+a))/3 > 3/(1/(a+b) + 1/(b+c) + 1/(c+a))$$
$$2t/3 > 3/(1/(a+b) + 1/(b+c) + 1/(c+a))$$
$$2t/9 > 1/(1/(a+b) + 1/(b+c) + 1/(c+a))$$

$$1/(a+b+c) = 1/t$$

So,

$$t/9 + 2t/9 - 1/t > 1/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c) + 1/(1/(a+b) + 1/(b+c) + 1/(c+a)) - 1/(a+b+c)$$

That means $1/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c) + 1/(1/(a+b) + 1/(b+c) + 1/(c+a)) - 1/(a+b+c)$ can maximally become $t/3 - 1/t$

For $n=n$ the answer is similar: $3t/n^2 - 1/t$

What allowed maximally infinite value for your expression is that, the same inequality worked in opposite ways, because one of your fractions had the opposite sign of the other. In such cases, appropriately chosen values usually allow you to reach infinity. As an exercize, choose $a=t$ and $b=+/-0, c=+/-0$ and analyze.

Comment: Im sorry, but i enforced that a,b,c are integers $>0$? Was my edit too late before you replied? Does your argument go through even for integers?

Comment: Ahh.. Either way, I didn't write my answer with a,b,c being positive and integer in mind. I will think again.

Comment: Positivity is an okay condition but forcing integers makes everything very difficult, because usually this kind of problems heavily rely on inequality theorems which usually assume either real numbers or positive real numbers and result in accordingly, such as the one I used.

Comment: Hey I edited twice, take a look

Comment: Lets also suppose that t/n is an integer in order to avoid this other cases. It is clear that when we set the a=b=c=t/3, then we can calculate the sum, but its not clear to me, what should this uniform weight distribution be the optimum. Do you have any intuition in this direction?

Comment: If you assume $a=\frac{t}{3}-k$, $b=\frac{t}{3}$ and $c=\frac{t}{3}+k$, then the first two parantheses (ignorin $\frac{1}{a+b+c}$, because it is constant $=1/t$) become $$\frac{9t^2-27k^2}{t(t-3k)(t+3k)}$$. There is no reason to assume such an arithmetic progrression among $a,b,c$ but my experience tells me that if you are looking for extremas such as the maximum value, those cases occur when some simetries exist among the variables.

Comment: This is why I initially suggested $a=b=c=t/3$, because it has the best simetry; the next thing I tried was $a=1, b=t/3, c=2t/3-1$, but it didn't provide a better answer than the first. However sometimes the answer can be more weird such as $a=t/2, b=t/3, c=t/6$. My point is generally maximums or minimum achieved not randomly but by satisfying some simetry issues or weird properties in math :)

Comment: Notice that $\frac{t}{3}>k-->t>3k$ and when $k=0$, we have $a=b=c=t/3$ as I showed before. Now look at this expression from before:
$$\frac{9t^2-27k^2}{t(t^2-9k^2)}$$ (Denomiator rearranged) 
If you set $k=0$, then you maximize the numerator. But if you try to minimize $t^2-9k^2$, then you can minimize the denominator. Both cases increase the value of the fraction, however you cannot achieve both of them, $k=0$ and  $t^2-9k^2$ as small as possible, at the same time; because they work against each other.

Comment: So, I would say the maximum value is achieved somewhere in between them; you can think of it as a balance for $k$, between $k^2$ being as close to as $0$ or $t^2/9$. And I strongly believe that that balance is based on t, it is not constant, which makes it even harder to figure out. What I would suggest, as you have no theoretical value or a way to figure out that balance at the moment, is that focus on minimizing the denominator; because reducing denominator has a bigger impact on the growth of the fraction than increasing the numerator.

Comment: I previously wrote $a=1, b=t/3, c=2t/3-1$ did not work better, but now I realized maybe I was wrong. For the attempt to maximize the numerator, set $k^2=0$, then the fraction becomes $9/t$. For the attemp to minimize the denominator, let's say $t^2-9k^2=p$ and we will try to keep $p$ as small as possible, but not $0$, because it would make $a=0$ which violates positivity (would result in infinite value though). So, if $t^2-9k^2=p$, then the fraction becomes, $$\frac{6t^2+3p}{tp}$$ Since this is an easier fraction, and we know that we should keep $p$ as small as possible, we can evaluate that.

Comment: $t$ is constant and depending on $p$, we are trying to maximize $\frac{6t^2+3p}{tp}$. Since there is only one (non-constant) variable is left, now we can analyze its derivative to find its maxima. For whatever value of $p$ the derivative is $0$, for that value the fraction will have its maximum or minimum. (Back then we couldn't do it, because $a,b,c$, all three were non-constant variables [and I don't know but maybe multivariable-calculus could help there, but I don't know it]). The derivative of the fraction is $$\frac{-6t}{p^2}$$

Comment: However, this fraction, $\frac{-6t}{p^2}$, doesn't have a root; but as $p$ approaches to infinity, derivative approaches to $0$, but we still don't know whether it is a maximum or a minimum. I used an online tool, derivative-calculator.net to see the graphs. It turned out that for $p$ approaching to infinity, the fractions approaches its minimum (which is zero), but the maximum is where $p$ approaches to $0$, which is not a root of the derivative, because that maximum of the fraction when $p$ approaches to 0 is asymtotic, meaning that it doesn't have $0$ slope like a regular maximum would have

Comment: I just noticed that $\frac{6t^2+3p}{tp}=\frac{6t}{p}+\frac{3}{t}$ which is much easier to evaluate (for some reason I didn't expect this simplicity). With this new form, it was already clear that the fraction has its maximum when $p$ is as small as possible. Back to topic, we can only choose $p$ a positive integer because $p=t^2-9k^2$ where $t$ and $k$ are integers and $t>3k$. Just remember, $p$ is how much away $t^2$ from $9k^2$ is, and $k$ was how much $a$ and $c$ were away from $b$. Now, we keep $p$ small, give it $1$ and see in the next comment.

Comment: $$\frac{6t^2+3}{t}$$ is the highest you can get just by trying to minimize the denominator, which, however, will also reduce the numerator and that will reduce the value of the fraction. Remember, I mentioned the "balance". For big $t$, denominator becomes more and more important than the numerator; this is why that "balance" is dependant on $t$. Now choose $a=1, b=$t/3, c=2t/3-1$, I will do so too.

I'm done with this. Overall, I couldn't tell you the theoretically most optimized answer, but showed you a way to minimize the denominator to keep your fraction at least decently big. It was fun

Comment: Okay I couldnt hold myself back from writing it but here is the fraction:
$$\frac{-2t^4+12t^3-9t^2+18t-27}{2t(t+3)(t-1)(2t-3)}$$

Don't forget that this is when $a,b,c$ are in arithmetic progression with $b=t/3$ and when not the whole fraction is tried to be maximized but simply the denominator is tried to be minimied. And don't forget that this is ignoring $-\frac{1}{a+b+c}$ in the original fraction which is simply $-\frac{1}{t}$. If you are so interested, you can include $-\frac{1}{t}$ and evaluate it analitically such as by differentiating and solving it for $0$ to see which $t$ is best.